# Are discussion of mythology-related pseudo-science off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

This question caught my attention:

[image]

Which is asking about the [Ancient Astronaut Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_astronaut_hypothesis), a pseudo-science hypothesis, positing that mythological beings (in this case the Anunnaki, a group of Mesopotamian deities), are in fact extra-terrestrials.   Fun in movies sometimes, but not usually all that academically interesting.

Should this sort of question be considered off topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Off-topic** because it's not about mythology, it's about pseudo-science.

Of course, the title of the question "who were the Anunnaki according to Sumerians' tales", is on-topic. But if you click through you realise the question is bad:

- The question can be easily answered as a general reference
- The OP is asking about an alternative, pseudo-scientific explanation, which is not mythological

If the question was asking about whether Thor was an alien (because Marvel), it would be off-topic fo the same reasons.