# What should be the defining cutoff for when something is mythology?

Tags: discussion, scope

There has been a lot of controversy in Meta and chat about what is and what is not on topic as far as fictional sources, religions, and whatnot.

- [Should we allow tags for external media?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/should-we-allow-tags-for-external-media)
- [Are fictional mythologies on topic?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140/are-fictional-mythologies-on-topic/143#comment259_143)
- [Is Cthulhu on or off topic?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/is-cthulhu-on-or-off-topic)
- [Is scientology on topic here?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-scientology-on-topic-here)
- [Are discussion of mythology-related pseudo-science off-topic](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/are-discussion-of-mythology-related-pseudo-science-off-topic)
- [How will we define mythology?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-will-we-define-mythology)

I think things like this are going to keep cropping up, and we need to have a **clear, simple, easily referenced** cutoff criteria in order to be fair to all current and future users.

What should this criteria be?

Answer (score 6):

**No, Age shouldn't be the deciding factor**. Age isn't a very good criteria, it sure has *something* to say, but shouldn't be the be all end all.

For a (purely hypothetical) example: Assume that some Amazonian tribe has a creation myth, but according to it, the world is ~500 years old (so the myth is about ~1500 or something), that would be completely off topic due to age, even though it *is* an actual mythology.

A better way would be to split by fictional and real mythology. this would result in a debate about what is a fictional mythology and what is not, and for that we could use what LessPop_MoreFizz said [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21468362#21468362)

> the thing that's fictional isn't the content of the myth. It's the myth itself that's fictional.
>
> Greek mythology is fiction, but it isn't fictional - it represents actual stories told by actual people about their actual beliefs at an actual time and place in history.

Comment: This doesn't do anything to settle the debates about Cthulhu, Scientology and so forth

Comment: Cthulhu is a fictional myth as far as I know, it's a myth in the Lovecraft books that did end up being true in that fictional universe. I don't know enough about any mythology surrounding scientology to answer your point on that.

Comment: I'd +1 in agreement, but I don't want to upvote an answer that answers "What should we use?" with "Not age.". I realize that this was in response to durron597's first answer that advocated a hard cutoff based on age, but that answer is no longer around.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman The second part of my answer provides something we could use, namely a clear definition of fictional myth vs real myth (or it seems clear to me anyway)

Comment: @Arperum: Ah, you're right. I overlooked that. I still don't agree with your recommended cutoff though.

Comment: @Arperum - the criteria is pretty clear without needing to know Scientology. Travolta is a real person and he believes it. Case closed.