# Are modern-day flat-earth myths on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I find myself curious about flat-earth theories, and wondering if they count as myths for the sake of this site.  As per [this question](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-should-be-the-defining-cutoff-for-when-something-is-mythology), age is not hugely important.

I'm sure questions about [Nüwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_creation_myths#N%C3%BCwa) holding up the sky would be okay, but maybe there is a distinction I'm missing.

**Question**: Are modern-day flat-earth myths on-topic?

Comment: Note that there are two kinds of flat-earthers, those that actually believe it, and those that play it as a game. The latter group will give much more intelligent answers, but it's not obvious that the topic would count as  a myth in their case. ¶ Since you've received no answers to this question yet, why not simply post your question and see whether it gets any off-topic votes?

Answer (score 5):

I think we need to be careful about the word myth. There are two definitions of the word. One involves traditional stories that encode values and beliefs about the world. The other is just a synonym for "false belief."

The former is well on topic here, but the latter is more appropriate for something like the Skeptics stack.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why they would not be on-topic.  Especially with relation to derivation from older cultures or theories.

After all, most ancient cultures knew the world was round.  Flat-earth theories only seemed to arrive in mediaeval times in the west.  So, a good topic for questions.

Comment: flat earth is a political propaganda invented in 'enlightment' to ridicule so-called 'middle ages'